# query string and type nested (elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my mapping:

```
{
  "name": {
    "type": "text",
  },
  "my_array": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "first": {
        "type": "text",
      },
      "last": {
        "type": "text",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Document 1:

```
{
  "my_array": [
    { "first": "John", "last": "Smith" },
    { "first": "Alice", "last": "White" }
  ]
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
  "name": "John"
}
```

Is there any way to make this query string query return both documents without using a [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-nested-query.html)?

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "John"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Elasticsearch 6.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can nest the `query_string` query inside a `nested` query that works on both nested fields, like this:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "my_array",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "my_array.*",
                "query": "John"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "name",
            "query": "John"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want Elasticsearch to return both documents with the simple query string query in my question. I have updated my question.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly, that's the closest you can get as the `query_string` query language doesn't support querying nested fields (yet)